# Network icon disappears from tray

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, system-tray

I got 12.04 LTS but it happened in 11.10 too.
The thing is that the network icon disappears from tray without any warning. I've noticed it happens when the connection is weak and unstable, but I know it is just a graphical problem because it still works when it manages to reconnect automatically. When it doesn't, I can't find another way to put it back other than killing the X server or simply rebooting the OS.
But come on, this is Linux, obviously there is a way to solve this. So

1. How I make it not to disappear ever again?
2. At least, what can I do to make it reappear (I suppose with a command in terminal)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed related wireless drivers.

## Workaround:

When it gets disconnected, first restart the network manager:

> sudo service network-manager restart

Then bring back the tray applet:

> nm-applet

---

If this works, the solution for now, is to make a bash script which you can simply execute when it gets disconnected again.

Running a command like,

> ping www.google.com -S 1

will help with keeping the connection alive.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. But what can I do if the connection breaks? I know it will, because my WiFi network in the university is very unstable. By the way, I don't use mobile connections.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem with 12.04, whenever I am disconnected from Internet, after sometime the Network Manager Icon disappears from the Top Panel, but still the daemon or the service is running at the background. Going to Network, I am able to configure connections, but How can I exactly bring back the network manager Icon at the Top panel, or how can I avoid it from disappearing ?

Comment: I had no solution for this. In fact, I changed mi laptop and this never happened again, so I suppose it was some kind of hardware-software conflict. By that time, I had a Compaq with some Atheros network card, I don't remember well.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I changed my laptop and this never happened again so I cannot test it. Let's see if @Pras does. By the way, ping didn't help.